# How to join a template variable with brackets in js?

Tags: javascript

I got the function taking the input name as a parameter.

```
function getInputs(inputName) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=${inputName}[]]`);
}
```

I want to join it to the brackets but it throws the [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FhvU.png)

The input name looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMwXs.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getInputs(inputName) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${inputName}[]"]`);
}
```

Surround your attribute selector value with quotes.

Comment: Thanks!! It helped a lot.